# For loop not working for generating docx file in docxtpl in python

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I am using `docxtpl` module to generate handful of documents with the data that I have. My data are stored as a list of dictionaries. I have written a `for` loop for that, yet in each iteration my `for` loop generates a docx document with the information of the first dictionary! Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

I leave a sample Python code here so as to give a better overview of the problem!

```py
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from docx2pdf import convert

doc = DocxTemplate('Hello.docx')

list = [{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Amin'}, {'name': 'Carl'}]

for i in range(3):
    doc.render(list[i])
    doc.save('test'+str(i)+'.docx')
```

My docx is as simple as:

```
Hello my name is {{ name }}
```

I want to generate 3 different word documents with the names John, Amin, and Carl.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is kind of messed up.
And the variable `list` is protected, so you should rename the list:

```
list_of_names = [{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Amin'}, {'name': 'Carl'}]
```

I would instead loop over the list itself, and access the values straight from there.

```
for item in list_of_names:
    doc.render(item)  
    doc.save(f"test{item['name']}.docx")
```

I'm not sure, but you may need to open the template document with each iteration. In that case, the code should look like this:

```
for item in list_of_names:
    doc = DocxTemplate('Hello.docx')
    doc.render(item)  
    doc.save(f"test{item['name']}.docx")
```

Please, let me know if it works as expected :)