# Creating a report with docxtpl

Tags: python, templates, docx, docxtpl

I want to create a docx report with the information that I get from an excel. Lets say I have an excel like this

Name       Biography         Age
john       He is a doctor.   30
michael    he is an actor.   31
Lary       He is a student.  22

My world should look like

[Some cover]

name: john

Biography:He is a doctor.

Age: 30

---

name:Michael

Biography:He is an actor

Age:31

---

name:Lary

Biography: He is a student

Age:22

---

Basically I have used the similar code within this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69987020/for-loop-not-working-for-generating-docx-file-in-docxtpl-in-python). But the difference is that I would like to collect all them in the same docx.

My codes output is like:

name:Lary

Biography: He is a student

Age:22

Because it overwrites the template into my output word.

My question is that how can I append every person instead of overwriting every time?

Answer (score 1):

First, create a nested dictionary with your data:

```
people_dict = {'John':{"Age":29, "Bio": "Doctor"}, 
               'Michael':{"Age":34, "Bio": "Actor"},
               'Larry':{"Age":45, "Bio": "Student"}}
```

Then, in your template create a `for` loop to iterate over `people_dict`:
[image: screenshot of template for loop]

Next, create the `context` variable with `context = {'people_dict':people_dict}`.

Render the `context` and the output will be:
[image: output of script]

I figured this out by referencing this [Jinja2 documentation on loops and conditionals](https://ttl255.com/jinja2-tutorial-part-2-loops-and-conditionals/)